# Why AppendTo is much faster than Table for tracking object movement

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I need to track some objects, the simplified version something like this

```
Clear[f];
list1 = Table[Table[f[u], {u, 0., t, 2 Pi/360}], {t, 0., 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10000}]; // AbsoluteTiming

list2 = Module[{L = {}, i = 0, dt = 2 Pi/360.}, Table[If[i dt <= t, AppendTo[L, f[dt i++]]];  L,
 {t, 0., 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10000}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

list1 == list2
```

> {0.518511, Null}
> {0.0090028, Null}
> True

In my impression, `AppendTo` is often relatively slow.
I prefer the first `Table` based solution, but here `Table` is much worse than `AppendTo`, and the AppendTo based solution is a bit complicated, is there a simple and efficient way?

**Background**
[equilateral-triangle-inscribed-in-an-ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717238/equilateral-triangle-inscribed-in-an-ellipse)
Using Table to track point $M$ is simple, however it will cause a lot of repetition calculations, so I consider using `Appendto`

1. Table based approach

```
Manipulate[Module[{a = 3, b = 2, P, Q, R, M, sol, α}, 
P = {a*Cos[α], b*Sin[α]};
Q = {a*Cos[β], b*Sin[β]}; 
R = RotationTransform[-Pi/3, Q][P];
M = (P + Q + R)/3; 
sol := NSolve[Function[{x, y}, x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2==1] @@ R && 0<=α<β<6*Pi, β, Reals][[1]]; 
α = α1; 
Graphics[{{Circle[{0, 0}, {a, b}]}, 
 {Point[Table[M /. sol, {α, 0., α1, 2*Pi/180}]]}, 
 {Opacity[0.2], Polygon[{P, Q, R}]}, Disk[M, 0.05]} /. sol,
 PlotRange -> 1.1*Max[a, b], Axes -> True]], {α1, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

2. AppendTo based approach
   More smoothly, but it also has some issue, like excess trajectory are generated when the slider goes back.

```
Manipulate[Module[{a = 3, b = 2, P, Q, R, M, sol}, 
P = {a*Cos[α], b*Sin[α]}; 
Q = {a*Cos[β], b*Sin[β]}; 
R = RotationTransform[-Pi/3, Q][P]; 
M = (P + Q + R)/3;
sol = NSolve[Function[{x, y}, x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1] @@ R && 0<=α<β<6*Pi, β, Reals][[1]];
Graphics[{{Circle[{0, 0}, {a, b}]}, {Point[AppendTo[L, M /. sol]]}, 
{Opacity[0.2], Polygon[{P, Q, R}]}, Disk[M, 0.05]} /. sol,
 PlotRange -> 1.1*Max[a, b], Axes -> True]], {L, {}, None}, {α, 0, 2*Pi},
 TrackedSymbols :> {α}]
```

Comment: What's the definition of `f[u]`?

Comment: I guess you may clean the memory first. Also, you can use this syntax: `Table[xxx,{x,0,n},{y,0,m}]`

Comment: @ChrisK I think it's not important here.

Comment: Why not just calculate the full list `Table[f[u], {u, 0., 2 Pi, 2 Pi/360}]` once and truncate it as required at the point of use?

Comment: @SimonWoods This is a good approach for simplified versions, but I'm not sure its performance in `Manipulate`(last example), I hope to compute in real time smoothly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both codes construct of a list of lists.

In the first code, the list in each entry of the result is constructed by `Table`.

If the second code, the list in each entry of the results is construct by adding an element to the list of the previous entry. [*Update:* I probably should have added: The element is added to the previous entry, only when needed, which is not every iteration.]

I think it's clear that adding one element, even in a slightly expensive way, is faster than adding an average of 180 elements.  The `AppendTo` method is not 180 times† faster; rather, it's more like 50 times faster.

†*Update:*
I forgot to account for the fact that `AppendTo` is not called every iteration. In fact `AppendTo` is called only 361 times in all, which results in $\left({361 \atop 2}\right)= 65341$ elements being copied or added to `L` over all the times it is updated. `Table`, OTOH, adds 1.8M elements to the sublists in all.  There are also other slightly slow operations, the comparison `i dt <= t` that is done each iteration and `i++`.  Against that is something that is faster:  When `L` is added to the list being constructed via a pointer and is not copied; the only copying happens when `AppendTo` is called. The data structure we end up with in the second code takes up a significantly smaller memory. The smaller size also represents less work needed to construct it. Sorting out the significance of each of these effects is beyond me at this point.

Here's a test (ten times the size of the OP's codes) if you are unfamiliar with this aspect of Mathematica (or if, like me, you forgot about it for a while):

First code:

```
Quit[]

list1 = Table[
    Table[f[u], {u, 0., t, 2 Pi/360}], {t, 0., 2 Pi, 
     2 Pi/100000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.09715, Null}  *)

ByteCount@list1
(*  1308034520  *)

MemoryInUse[]
(*  1399784184  *)
```

Second code:

```
Quit[]

list2 = Module[{L = {}, i = 0, dt = 2 Pi/360.}, 
    Table[If[i dt <= t, AppendTo[L, f[dt i++]]]; 
     L, {t, 0., 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100000}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.055307, Null}  *)

ByteCount@list2
(*  1308034520  <-- roughly the same! *)

MemoryInUse[]
(*    93447328  <-- 1/15 of the amount in the list 1 case *)
```

Note `ByteCount` returns how much memory it would take to store the whole expression and does not account for shared points to identical sublists.

Answer (score 2):

For another way to go about this, we may turn to look at the result and apply [`Counts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html):

```
list1 // Counts /* Values
(*
{28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, \
27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28,<<301>>, 28, 27, 28,\
28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, \
28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 1 }
*)
```

We see that this is quite regular and simply depends on the divisibility of $t$ by $\frac{2\pi}{360}$, i.e., the step for the inner range of $u$. We may thus use these *multiplicities* and apply them to the list of lists with the $f[\cdot]$ that is rather simple to construct. Note that the `FoldList[ List /* Flatten ]` in the code below works a bit like `Accumulate`.

```
list3 = With[
    {
        repetitions = #/(2 Pi/360) & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10000] // Floor/*Counts/*Values,
        elements = { f[#] } & /@  Range[0., 2. Pi, 2. Pi/360] // FoldList[ List/*Flatten ]
    }
    ,
    Flatten[ MapThread[ ConstantArray, { elements, repetitions } ], 1 ]

]; //AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0648518, Null} *)

MemoryInUse[]
(* 106073744 *)

list3 == list2
(* True *)
```

So this is about six times slower than the `AppendTo` solution on my machine. Unfortunately, we need to use infinite precision (e.g., not use real numbers) for the repetitions as slight rounding errors will make the solution not match completely (albeit the difference is marginal).

Instead of `MapThread` one can also use `Inner` with about the same speed:

```
Flatten[ Inner[ ConstantArray, elements, repetitions, List ], 1 ]
```

Comment: If one could live with the marginal differences by using real numbers for `repetitions`, then this approach turns out to be about as fast as the `AppendTo` approach.